# Left Align Latex Matrix in Markdown

Tags: markdown, mathjax

For example

```
$B=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$
```

This code is center-aligned in MarkDown by default. How do I left align it? I tried other answers, but they don't work, and they don't seem specific to writing in Markdown.

I also tried the following, but the latex doesn't seem to execute this way and prints just a plain text.

```
<p align = "left">
$B=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$
</p>
```

The following output for suggested code does not work:
[image]

Comment: How can I reproduce the problem? I tried to reproduce it on upmath.me, but even your example did not work (I have no experience with markdown)

Comment: Hi. I work with Markdown in jupyter in VSCode, but you may try it in JupyterNotebook also. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to make a real left-aligned matrix in this environment. But you could fake it by using an array!

```
$
\left[
\begin{array}{ll}
    1 & 1  \\
    1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$
```

[image: left justified array with square brackets]

---

There's also the \phantom{} command, which could help in case it is the minus-sign which throws of your alignment. It adds an invisible character (in our case the minus-sign), which you could use to manually adjust the layout of your matrix.

```
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 1  \\
    \phantom{-}1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. It does not work for me. Did you try it in Mardown. I've attached the output above. Thanks.

Comment: I checked both examples in JupyterNotebook (the free trial thing). The screenshots are from there. Maybe you can check it online too, and then find out what's different in your local version. I don't understand why your $-signs get rendered, maybe there's a difference there?

Comment: Hi. It does seem to work in the JupyterNotebook online. However because I use JupyterNotebook inside VisualStudio Code, that might be the reason for the problem. Thanks.